# What she was doing here OR What was she doing here

Tags: word-choice, phrases, questions, phrase-choice

which one is correct?

> "I don't know **what she was doing here**"

Or

> "i don't know **what was she doing here**"

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Wasn't there a recent thread somewhat related to this? Lemme look . . . http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-wheres-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is/36640#36640 That might have enough info for you, perhaps. :)

Answer (score 2):

"**I** don't know what she was doing here" is correct. We do not invert subject and verb in indirect questions.