# What's the right order of the words?

Tags: word-order

Consider this sentence:

*The first point I feel the need to address is why it is important to ask such a question*.

Is it grammatically correct or should it be *why is it important...*? Why? What's the grammar behind it?

Comment: I don't remember the exact question but I think this is a dup.

Comment: Also related [“Do you know where's Linda?” vs “Do you know where Linda is?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-wheres-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is)

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use either, but you'd need different punctuation. Further, for clarity, I'd stick a colon after the first "is."

So:

*The first point I feel the need to address is: why it is important to ask such a question.*

or

*The first point I feel the need to address is: why is it important to ask such a question?"

Here is where "forgot the grammar terms as I internalized them" is a handicap for me. Sorry. Basically, the first version ("why it is") translates to "I want to explain why asking this question is important." This is explaining, not a question. But the second version ("why is it") turns the statement into a question because of that word-order, and therefore requires a question mark.

Either one would be acceptable, though the nuances are slightly different, and the first one feels more formal. (Because it's not a question, and therefore is more "firm.")