# "What's he hiding?” vs. "What he's hiding?"

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct between:

> "What's he hiding?"

and:

> "What he's hiding?"

I heard the first one from a film but not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Since when do film characters use formal English that sounds grammatical, or is grammatically sound?

Comment: What're are you saying? [Is that] What you're saying? Please note: It is practically impossible to understand real dialogue until you learn the basic forms. After that, you will understand dialogue better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Do you know where's Linda?" vs "Do you know where Linda is?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-wheres-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but not of that question.  It deals with subordinate interrogatives, while this deals with a main clause interrogative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, when forming questions that begin with special words like *what*, *how*, *when* etc. (called question words), [**the auxiliary verb**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs) or any of the several forms of the *to be* verb should necessarily always precede the subject. In fact, breaking this rule makes your questions sound very unnatural. So, that's why only the first sentence is grammatical:

> What's he hiding?

The other sentence would be grammatical if you split it into two separate sentences like this:

> What? He's hiding?

As I said above, the only time the auxiliary verb or any of the several forms of the verb *to be* are placed before the subject is when you begin your question with a question word. In all other cases, it's entirely possible to leave the grammar completely untouched and instead use a rising intonation to indicate to your listener that what you're asking is a question.

Comment: The question meaning of an utterance is normally signaled by rising intonation in speech, and punctuation in writing; its (the utterance's) syntax needn't necessarily be interrogative.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be correct in the proper context.

> **What's he hiding**?  Let's find out.

and

> A: What do we want to find?
>   B: (we want to find) **What he's hiding.**

The first is short for the complete sentence *what is he hiding*, and the second is an [ellipsis](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ellipsis) of a sentence that uses the subordinate clause *what he is hiding*.

Comment: But your second example is not a question. I thought the OP was asking about the difference between **What's he hiding?** and **What he's hiding?** To me, both appear to be questions. Also notice that they both begin with a capital letter.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin  Er ... you're quite right.