# "Where there was food?" Vs. "Where was there food?"

Tags: questions, interrogatives, existentials

What is the correct interrogative structure of **existential clause** in present and past tense?

> Choice 1 (A): "**was there** food?"
>
> Choice 2 (A):  "**there was** food?"

Another example just with additional question word:

> Choice 1 (B) "**Where was there** food?"
>
> Choice 2 (B) "**Where there was** food?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Do you know where's Linda?" vs "Do you know where Linda is?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-wheres-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm not sure it's a duplicate.  There may be more depth to this question than the one in your link.  Please see my answer.

Comment: I've changed your tag "existential-clause" to the more common one used in ELL `existentials` for easier referencing.

Comment: Can you show a reference that supports you new term? The term "existential clause" is the most widely used in the literature to describe such sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interrogative form of a statement must include or imply a statement.

Case 1: **"There was food."** is a statement

**The interrogative** of "There was x." is "**Was there x?**

Just like: "There is x" and "Is there x?"

Case 2: "There was food on the table". **On the table** is an adverbial phrase. It is the **place where** the food was.

The interrogative here would be: "**Where was there food?**" Answer: "**There was food on the table**." OR **"There was food there or over there.** [if you are pointing at it]

The phrase "where there was food" is a relative clause. It can work like this:

I was looking for the guests in the room **where there was food**.

**It cannot stand alone unless it is a continuation of a dialogue as given by Andrew in his answer**. But  if you are starting a conversation  yourself, you cannot just say: "Where there was food". That would not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the existential sentence:

> There was food.

The *existential* question form would be:

> **Was there food**?

Other examples:

> There was a house on a high hill ⇒ **Was there a house on a high hill**?
>
> There were many fruit trees surrounding the house ⇒ **Were there many fruit trees surrounding the house?**

The same is true for verbs other than "to be", although this structure can seem overly formal, dramatic, and/or literary (although the existential statement itself is already somewhat *literary*):

> There lived in that house an old man and an old woman ⇒ **Lived there in that house an old man and an old woman**?

More common would be:

> **Did** an old man and an old woman **live** there, in that house?

That being said: It's not uncommon to hear an existential phrase spoken as a question, to indicate the speaker believes the statement is true:

> A: I went to the meeting last night.  It was incredibly boring.
>   B:  **There was food**?
>   A:  Yes, at least there was food.

It's also possible to phrase the question as in your second example:

> A: Last night I went to this meeting -
>   B: **Where there was food?**
>   A:  Yes, there was food at the meeting.  But it was so boring it wasn't really worth it.

Again, this are both slightly *literary*.  Simple questions are more common:

> Was there food (there)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So when I add a question word (why, where etc.) how should I build the existential clause? (Is "Where was there food" is Ok?)

Comment: @subtle_sibling  I'm not sure if, technically, *"Where was there food?"* is an existential question, because the focus is on the *location* of the food, not the *existence / nonexistence* of the food.  It depends what you want to know.

Comment: I want to know about the location of the existence of the food.

Comment: @subtle_sibling  how about, *"Where is it that there was food?"*  :)

Comment: No. I'm looking for the consistency in grammar and I'd like to know  exactly about the sentences that I posted, if they're correct or no for interrogative usage. I found a significant difference between your answer to Lambie's answer.

Comment: The OP doesn't understand what the term existential clause means. They have discovered the term, but they don't understand that using a "wh" word with "there is/are"changes the sentence from "existential" to a normal interrogative sentence. *There is a shop* (existential) and *Where is there a shop?" there (adverb) = locative

Comment: @subtle_sibling  Lambie's answer is fine, but we aren't really saying different things.  I assume you know how to phrase simple questions like *"Was there food?"* -- so you're looking for something deeper, related to  *existential sentences* and the related interrogatives.  *"Where is there food?"* is fine but I'm not sure it's an *existential* question.   My answer tries to explain less common and more literary ways to express this concept.   I doubt whether you'll need to use some of them, but hopefully you'll recognize them if you see them.

Answer (score 0):

1. You **were** hungry (*statement*)
2. **Were** you hungry? (*question*)
3. There **was** food [in the house].
4. **Was** there (any) food [in the house]?

In sentence 4, the speaker is asking whether the house contained any food.

5.(a)  Where **was** the food?

In sentence 5, the speaker is asking for the *location* of the food. The EXISTENCE of the food is implied in the question. They knew that *there was* food but not where to find it.

6. (a) It **was** in the shopping bags.
   (b) **There** was food in the shopping bags.

Sentence 6 tells the speaker where the food was.

5. (b) Where **was** there food?

Sentence 5 (b) is still asking for the location of the food, not if the food existed.

> If **there was** no food in the fridge, then where **was it**?

You could place *there* in place of "it" with no changing of meaning but it sounds slightly awkward.

Comment: It's the same answer as Lambie wrote. You could edit her answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @subtle_sibling I don't care about the upvotes or the downvotes. My aim was to show what "existential" means, which none of the answers actually addressed. I think Lambie's answer is good but to me it "looks" confusing, there is too much bold but that's her stylistic choice. Yesterday, I edited to "show" that their answer was correct. Existential sentence is practically the same as "existential clause". I mean, you understand what a sentence is, right?

Comment: @subtle_sibling Oh, and my answer does not replicate hers, she rightly speaks of relative clauses (brilliant point) and why starting a conversation with "Where was there food?" would not make sense, but then again you were not asking how to start a conversation, were you? You were interested in making existential interrogatives, but a question beginning with a wh-word (*what*, *where*, *why*, *when*, *who*, *whose*) is not asking about the existence of a thing or things.

Comment: This is a well-written answer that I think will be of use to future learners who visit the site.